# Is it possible to reload an XDocument and keep all existing references to it?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've got an XDocument created via XDocument's static Load method (taking an XmlReader) as follows:

```
XDocument doc;

doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Now, it's necessary at some point to reload the document (restoring to the original version after changes have been made). The obvious way to do this seems to be `doc = XDocument.Load(reader);`. However, this will create a new XDocument, and any existing references to `doc` will still point at the old (altered) version despite the fact that we've (re)loaded the original.

Is there a way to load an XmlReader (or even a string or byte[] representation of XML) into an existing XDocument, overwriting the contents? Or would I have to make all of the changes (dropping its elements and adding new ones) manually?

Comment: XDocument is merely a reference to an existing object, which in turn has more references to other objects and containers. This sounds like more of a scoping issue than a LINQ to XML issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
 doc.Root.ReplaceWith( XElement.Load(fileName));
```

If you want to preserve processing instructions you may need to Load into a temp XDocument first.

Comment: By "processing instructions" do you just mean actions performed on the XDocument after it is loaded but before it is used?

Comment: Additionally, would `doc.ReplaceWith(XDocument.Load(reader));` work as well, or run into the same issue as using `= new`?

Comment: With "processing instructions" I meant the Declaration (`<?xml ..>`).

Comment: XDocument.ReplaceWith should probably be do the trick as well. Might even be better.

Comment: It seems `doc.Root.ReplaceWith` works fine, but `doc.ReplaceWith` throws an InvalidOperationException with the message "Parent is missing". Can't find anything useful about it via Google, but looks like your suggestion works.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the root of the `XDocument`.

```
var oldDoc = new XDocument();
oldDoc.Add(new XElement("OldRoot"));
var newDoc = new XDocument();
newDoc.Add(new XElement("NewRoot"));
oldDoc.Root.ReplaceWith(newDoc.Root);
```